# Улучшение страницы справки «Что такое конкурс? Как его инициировать?»

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, справка

Заголовок: What is a bounty? How can I start one?
Ссылка не текущую версию на английском: https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

---

If you’ve [asked a good question](/questions/how-to-ask), [edited it](/helpcenter/editing) with status and progress updates, and still are [not receiving answers](/helpcenter/no-one-answers), you can draw attention to your question by placing a bounty on it.

A bounty is a special reputation award given to answers. It is funded by the personal reputation of the user who offers it, and is **non-refundable**. If you see a question that has not gotten a satisfactory answer, a bounty may help attract more attention and more answers. Slice off anywhere from +50 to +500 of your own hard-earned reputation, and [attach it to *any* question as a bounty](/privileges/set-bounties). You do not need to be the asker of the question to offer a bounty on it.

- **All bounties are paid for up front and non-refundable under any circumstances.**
- If your new reputation brings you below the requirement for any [privileges](/privileges), you will lose access to those privileges.
- Users may only have three active bounties at any given time.
- Questions may only have one active question bounty at any given time.
- To avoid overly promotional bounties, if you are offering a bounty on a question that you have already posted an answer to, your minimum spend is 100 reputation (not 50).
- Additionally, if you offer multiple bounties on the same question, the minimum spend doubles with each subsequent bounty (50 reputation on the first bounty, 100 reputation on the second, 200 on the third, and so on).
- You may not cancel a bounty once it has been started.

#### What happens when I start a bounty?

The bountied question will appear with a special indicator in all question lists, and it will also be visible on the [homepage Featured tab](/?tab=featured) for 7 days. Part of what you’re “paying for” with the bounty is to get additional attention for your question, over and beyond what a normal question gets. In that regard, a bounty does not *guarantee* a response,  and reputation refunds are not available if no answers are received as a result of the bounty.

#### How do I start a bounty? When can I start a bounty?

A bounty can be started on a question two days after the question was asked.

To start a bounty, click on the "start a bounty" link at the bottom of an eligible question and allocate anywhere between 50 and 500 reputation, in 50-point increments. You can also choose from [a list of bounty reasons](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/bounty-reasons-and-post-notices/) to help other users understand why you’re dissatisfied with any current answers to the question. If you need to describe something in more detail, there’s also optional, additional custom text that will be displayed with the bounty reason.

#### How is a bounty awarded?

The bounty period lasts $BountyDurationInDays days. Bounties must have a minimum duration of at least 1 day. After the bounty ends, there is a grace period of 24 hours to manually award the bounty. Simply click the bounty award icon next to each answer to permanently award your bounty to the answerer. (You cannot award a bounty to your own answer.)

If you do not award your bounty within $BountyDurationInDays days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount (or the full amount, if the answer is also accepted). If two or more eligible answers have the same score (their scores are tied), the oldest answer is chosen. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, no bounty is awarded to anyone.

If the bounty was started by the question owner, and the question owner accepts an answer posted during the bounty period, *and* the bounty expires without an explicit award then we assume the bounty owner liked the answer they accepted and award it the full bounty amount at the time of bounty expiration.

As a special bonus, any reputation you earn from being awarded a bounty is exempt from the daily reputation cap.

Answer (score 2):

Заголовок: Что такое конкурс? Как его инициировать?
Ссылка не текущую версию на английском: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

---

Если вы задали [хороший вопрос](/help/how-to-ask), [отредактировали](/help/editing) и обновили его, добавив актуальную информацию, но так и [не получили ответа](/help/no-one-answers), вы можете привлечь внимание к вопросу, назначив за него награду.

Награда — это репутация, которая вручается за ответы. Она присуждается из личной репутации пользователя, который начинает конкурс, и **не может быть изъята обратно**. Если вы планируете назначить награду за интересующий вас вопрос, на который никто не дал удовлетворительный ответ, учтите, [что у вас будут вычтены от 50 до 500 баллов репутации](/help/privileges/set-bounties). Чтобы предложить награду за ответ, необязательно быть автором вопроса.

- **Награда всегда назначается вперёд и не возвращается обратно ни при каких обстоятельствах.**
- Если после назначения награды ваша репутация становится ниже, чем требуется для конкретных [привилегий](/help/privileges), вы теряете к ним доступ.
- Одновременно можно начать только три конкурса.
- За один вопрос можно назначать только одну награду.
- Чтобы награда не использовались как откровенная реклама, за вопрос, на который вы уже дали ответ, вы можете назначить награду в минимум 100 баллов (не 50).
- Кроме того, если вы начинаете несколько конкурсов для одного вопроса, минимальный порог вознаграждения удваивается с каждым последующим вознаграждением (50 баллов за первое вознаграждение, 100 - за второе, 200 - за третье и так далее).
- После начала конкурса его нельзя отменить.

#### Что происходит, когда я начинаю конкурс?

Конкурсный вопрос, появится со специальным индикатором во всех списках вопросов и будет 7 дней отображаться во [вкладке «конкурсные» главной страницы](/?tab=featured). Ваши «расходы» на награду частично покрываются дополнительным вниманием к вашему вопросу, которое уделяется обычным вопросам. Награда не гарантирует ответ, а потраченная репутация не возвращается, если на конкурсный вопрос никто не ответит.

#### Как и где можно начать конкурс?

Конкурс можно начать только через два дня после создания вопроса.

Для этого, нажмите на ссылку «начать конкурс» в нижней части вопроса, к которому вы хотите привлечь внимание, и выберите от 50 до 500 баллов репутации с шагом 50 баллов. Также можно выбрать в списке [причину конкурса](/help/privileges/set-bounties), чтобы помочь другим пользователям понять, чем вас не устраивают текущие ответы. Если по вашему мнению требуется подробное описание причины конкурса, существует дополнительное специальное поле для ввода текста.

#### Как назначается вознаграждение?

Конкурс продолжается в течение 7 дней. Минимальная длительность конкурса – 1 день. После окончания конкурса наступает 24 часа «периода щедрости», в течение которых можно назначить победителя самостоятельно. Просто нажмите на символ награды рядом с любым ответом, чтобы окончательно присудить вашу награду автору ответа. Выбрать свой ответ нельзя.

Если в течение 7 дней (и «периода щедрости») ни один ответ не побеждает в конкурсе, половина суммы награды присуждается автору ответа, созданного после объявления о вознаграждении и получившего наибольший рейтинг (более 2 баллов). Если два или более ответа, подходящих под условия награды, имеют одинаковый рейтинг (т.е. в случае «ничьей» по баллам), награду получает первый по времени ответ. Если ни один ответ не подходит под условия награды, она не присуждается никому.

Если конкурс начинается автором вопроса и он отмечает один из ответов верным в течение периода щедрости, а затем этот период заканчивается без явного вручения награды, мы предполагаем, что автор удовлетворён полученным ответом, а награда в полном объеме присуждается автору выбранного ответа.

Вся репутация, полученная в конкурсных вопросах, не учитывается в ежедневном пределе изменения репутации.